# laravel - Collection forget subcollection

Tags: php, laravel

I have multidimensional collection, e.g.

```
Collection {#968 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    "Root Lorem Ipsum #1" => Collection {#980 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => {#970 ▼
          +"id": "5048"
          +"name": "lorem Ipsum"
          +"slug": "lorem-ipsum"
        }
        1 => {#972 ▶}
        2 => {#974 ▶}
      ]
    }
    "Root Lorem Ipsum #2" => Collection {#982 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Now I have filter for 'removing' duplicates:

```
    $categories = $categories->map(function ($chapter) {
        return $chapter->map(function ($category) use ($chapter) {
            if ($chapter->where('name', $category->name)->count() === 2) {
                $tmp = $chapter
                    ->where('name', $category->name)
                    ->where('id', '!=', $category->id)
                    ->first()
                ;

                $category->id = $category->id. ',' .$tmp->id;
                $chapter->forget($tmp);
            }

            return $category;
        });
    });
```

And on `$chapter->forget($tmp);` I want to remove it from collection but it's seems to not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The forget method removes an item from the collection by its key:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-forget

Since we are trying it on value part it's not working.

use unique method to filter unique records
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-unique

```
 $categories = $categories->map(function ($chapter) {
    return $chapter->map(function ($category) use ($chapter) {
       return $category->unique('name');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use link:

> $chapter->map(function ($category) use (**&**$chapter)